# Return parent Model column in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a table with

```
countries
      id , country_prefix
cities
      city_id, city_name, country_id,  city_prefix ,consumer_rates
```

Here is my models

```
class Country extends Model
{

   public function cities()
   {

      return $this->hasMany('App\City', 'country_id', 'id');
   }

}
```

Here is City model

```
 class City extends Model
 {

  protected  $primaryKey = 'city_id';

  public function country(){

    return $this->belongsTo('\App\Country','country_id','id');
  }

}
```

In my controller

```
$cities = Country::find($request->option)
        ->cities()
        ->select(['city_id', 'city_name', 'consumer_rates', 'city_prefix'])
        ->get();

    return response()->json($cities);
```

I need parent model column in my response with

city_id , city_name , consumer_rates, country_prefix and city_prefix

is there a clean way to achieve this ?

Comment: If you're interested in fetching your cities, why are you using your Country model to do the primary query? Wouldn't it make more sense to fetch like `City::whereHas('country', function($query){ $query->find(request()->option); })->get();`?

Comment: @CarterFort it return this error Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'cities.country_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `countries` where `cities`.`country_id` = `countries`.`id` and `countries`.`id` = 327 limit 1)

Comment: Did you add that column in your Cities migration? Can you post your migration code for your cities/countries tables?

Answer (score 1):

You can use your relation to query the parent model as:

```
City::whereHas('country', function($q) {
        $q->where('id', request()->option);
    })
    ->with('country')
    ->get();
```

Comment: This is precisely what I was suggesting. But you do need to make sure that your database columns are correct, which it sounds like maybe Adnan had not yet done. Although sometimes with this kinds of queries I get a DB error related to an ambiguous `id` column, in which case I'd have to change my where clause to look for `countries.id` instead of just `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
$country = Country::with('cities')->find($request->option);
$cities = $country->cities;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get it like this:

```
$response = DB::table('country')
    ->select('cities.city_id', 'cities.city_name','cities.consumer_rate','country.country_prefix','cities.city_prefix')
    ->join('cities', 'country.id', '=', 'cities.country_id')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

To attach it to the parent after using the `find()` method use the `load()` method to lazy load that relation:

```
$cities = Country::find($request->option)
    ->load(['cities' => function($query) {
        return $query->select(['city_id', 'city_name', 'consumer_rates', 'city_prefix']);
    }]);

return response()->json($cities);
```